# UITextfield text going beyond bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How do I keep a textfield's text from going beyond its *showable* bounds?

[image]

I am trying to make the textfield's width grow as the text inside of it grow but the textfield's text is going out of bounds nonetheless.

Comment: Are you want to increases the width if text field according to its text ?

Comment: Yes, and I am able to do so. The problem though is if the width is already going beyond the screen width, the above behavior happens

Comment: OK then it is better to use text view instead of using text field . Because in text field the text in only in one line

Comment: When you used text view then when the text goes out of screen it become in two line

Comment: @Ram that is the workaround I used to get the behavior I needed. Thanks for pointing me to that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func getWidth(text: String) -> CGFloat {
    let txtField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
    txtField.text = text
    txtField.sizeToFit()
    return txtField.frame.size.width
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, 
               shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, 
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let txtFieldWidth = getWidth(textField.text!)

    if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 100 > txtFieldWidth {
        txtWidthOfName.constant = 0.0

        if txtFieldWidth > txtWidthOfName.constant {
            txtWidthOfName.constant = txtFieldWidth
        }
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer I needed, but I also found this code from somewhere that helped me get to the behavior I needed